# Thin LVM pool frozen due to lack of free space, what to do?

Tags: linux, process, lvm

My thin LVM pool got full and some programs hung:

```
device-mapper: thin: 253:4: reached low water mark, sending event.
device-mapper: thin: 253:4: no free space available.
INFO: task jbd2/dm-6-8:742 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
INFO: task java:19262 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

I removed several thin snapshots to acquire some free space, but the programs didn't resume.

Is there a command to unfreeze programs/fs/volumes?

Comment: What happened to the programs? Did they detect a disk full condition and error out? Or are they blocked in a system call? What does `ps` say?

Comment: @Gilles They're blocked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a state of panic and it can't be solved without a reboot.

Reboot is tricky: even `reboot --force` didn't work for me, but this script did:

```
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
    echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

To prevent panic, some monitoring tool could either auto-delete old snapshots or call `fsfreeze` or both, but at least on rhel 6.5 no such tool exist.

The `lvm2-monitor` service can only print warning into syslog:

```
Apr 28 18:06:16 oktest-prod-lb1 lvm[789]: Thin vg_oktestlb1-pool-tpool is now 80% full.
Apr 28 18:07:26 oktest-prod-lb1 lvm[789]: Thin vg_oktestlb1-pool-tpool is now 85% full.
```

See `lvm.conf`:

```
# thin_library is the library used when monitoring a thin device.
#
# "libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so" monitors the filling of
# pool and emits a warning through syslog when the use of
# the pool exceeds 80%. The warning is repeated when 85%, 90% and
# 95% of the pool is filled.

thin_library = "libdevmapper-event-lvm2thin.so"
```

`rsyslog` can be configured to send an e-mail or run a shell command on such messages.

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
lvresize -L +100g oktestlb1/pool
```

or more generally:

```
lvresize -L +100g volgroup/poolname
```

This should immediately unfreeze the volume if you choose not to use event based auto-resize.  Of course you need room in your PV to do this.